# Voyager Laravel installation problem (composer)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, voyager

OS: **Centos 8**

PHP Version: **Multi-php** (7.2-default, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0)

Composer version **2.1.3**

---

I have initialed a new laravel project:

**/usr/bin/php74 /usr/local/bin/composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 test**

*(I'm using php 7.4 as a version)*

After installing the default laravel project is working fine. Afterwards I want to add **voyager**. I'm entering the folder with cd and then running the command..

**/usr/bin/php74 /usr/local/bin/composer require tcg/voyager**

after running the command i'm getting errors:

> Problem 1
> - tcg/voyager[1.4.x-dev, ..., 1.x-dev] require intervention/image ^2.4 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.4.0, ..., 2.5.1].
> - intervention/image 2.4.x-dev is an alias of intervention/image dev-master and thus requires it to be installed too.
> - tcg/voyager[v1.4.0, ..., v1.4.2] require league/flysystem ~1.0.41 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.41, ..., 1.0.x-dev] but the
> package is fixed to 1.1.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and
> that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for
> the update command.
> - intervention/image[dev-master, 2.4.0, ..., 2.5.1] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ~1.1 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] but
> the package is fixed to 2.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update
> and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument
> for the update command.
> - Root composer.json requires tcg/voyager ^1.4 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v1.4.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
>
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades,
> downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific
> versions.

After running it with -W parameter:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7.29, found laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but these were not loaded,
> likely because it conflicts with another require.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

I have tried this with different variations (different php versions, last laravel version and more - same result - **but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.**

I have read almost the whole internet with for this.., but nothing helped..

Answer (score 0):

composer require tcg/voyager --with-all-dependencies

try the above command

Comment: composer require tcg/voyager --with-all-dependencies is the same as composer require tcg/voyager --W (already tried). I have managed to install the system on Windows platform and then migrate to Linux server, but the problem still exists if you try directly on Linux - still do not have answer/solution for that..

Comment: Run Update composer  and restart your server and  then install voyager